# Grails - How to exclude some jars for grails-app(war) package

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Some unwanted wars are being included while maven's `grails-app` packaging. I need `itext-2.0.8`, which I added in `pom` and it is added fine, but below three jars are also getting added, and one is duplicate `itext-2.1.5`, this should not come into war file.

I tried exclude tag in maven corresponding plugin(export).

```
        <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

I tried by adding excludes in BuildConfig.groovy.

```
excludes "com.lowagie:itext:2.1.5"
excludes "com.lowagie:iTextAsian:2.1.5"
excludes "com.lowagie:itext-rtf:2.1.5"
```

Comment: What is the specific issue in sticking to `itext-2.1.5` provided by the plugin?

Comment: it comming from export plugin.